# Why does iPhone app resize for iPad but not iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, resize, xcode4.5

Why do original iPhone applications (normal screen size like iPhone 4/4s) in Xcode resize perfectly for iPad automatically and not for the slightly larger iPhone 5 screen size?

Comment: Are you talking about your own app, or other apps in general?

Comment: The iPhone applications are not resized perfectly on iPad automatically. They are just 2x scaled and cantered on the screen, which is far from perfect look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fit a iPhone 4 view  into the iPad each point is scaled equally into two directions. The aspect ratio of a iPhone4-point doesn't change on the iPad screen.

To fit a iPhone 4 view onto the iPhone 5 screen, each point has to be scaled in vertical direction only. This will distort each point and the view, similar to the distortions you get when you watch a movie in the wrong aspect ratio. A circle on the iPhone 4 screen won't be a circle on the iPhone 5. So you can't physically resize the pixels like it's done on the iPad.

In iOS-Development Autoresizing Masks come to the rescue. But there is no way to figure out if your app looks good if the auto resizing scales the view to iPhone 5 size. You have to test each app on a iPhone 5 sized screen. Apple didn't want to do this, so they put an opt-in in place, which you actively had to enable. They choose to use the iPhone5 launch image for that.

If your app looks good when it's vertically scaled simply provide the appropriate launch image.
If you used best practices to develop your iPhone 4 app that's basically all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 5 support needs to be explicitly added by supplying a "Default-568h" start image.

Comment: While what you say is true, I do not believe that is what @JamesBrown is asking.